# How to add a logo on a page?

Tags: graphics, formatting, includegraphics

I would like to add my school logo on the first page of a document.

On another question I found the following code. Unfortunately it changes all the spacing on the page (see the two screenshots with and without that snippet):

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.north west) ++ (2.5,-4) node {\includegraphics{heig-vd-black.pdf}};
```

[image]

Here the code I used for this example:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={18cm, 25cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\handlines}{
    \vspace{0.2cm}\rule{8cm}{0.2pt}\vspace{0.4cm}\newline\rule{8cm}{0.2pt}\vspace{0.4cm}\newline\rule{8cm}{0.2pt}
}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\sffamily\large}{Problème \thesection~-- }{0.2em}{}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\small\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*2}{*1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*2}{*1}

\newcommand\pts[1]{\small\color{points}\emph{(#1 pt)}}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\begin{document}

\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
\title{TITLE}

\maketitle

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
\path (current page.north west) ++ (2.5,-4) node {\includegraphics{heig-vd-black.pdf}};

Nulla auctor nibh lacus, in placerat ipsum auctor ut. Praesent ex ex, consectetur eu ante at, vehicula euismod enim. Curabitur erat lorem, efficitur eget lobortis a, sollicitudin nec velit. Sed scelerisque volutpat felis, finibus porttitor mauris rutrum sed. Aenean congue arcu quis lacus placerat vestibulum. Pellentesque pretium iaculis pulvinar. Nulla sit amet ligula lorem. Maecenas consectetur venenatis sodales.

Aenean congue arcu quis lacus placerat vestibulum. Pellentesque pretium iaculis pulvinar. Nulla sit amet ligula lorem. Maecenas consectetur venenatis sodales.

\textbf{Etiam molestie lectus ex, sed hendrerit enim consequat egestas.}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.3pt}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nec felis facilisis, tincidunt felis id, lobortis elit. Vestibulum hendrerit molestie posuere. Phasellus cursus elementum laoreet. Vivamus accumsan nisl in felis luctus pulvinar in ac arcu. Etiam vulputate feugiat sem eget mollis.

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|p{8cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Question} & \textbf{Réponse} \\ \hline
    Question 1 & \handlines \\ \hline
    Question 2 & \handlines \\ \hline
    Question 3 & \handlines \\ \hline
    Question 4 & \handlines \\ \hline
    Question 5 & \handlines \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clean the preamble of all unnecessary packages.

Comment: @AndréC it's done

Comment: Good, but the `graphicx` package is loaded twice.

Comment: Put `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
 \path (current page.north west) ++ (2.5,-4) node
{\includegraphics{heig-vd-black.pdf}};}%` at the end of the first paragraph.